# Stripe with multiple webhooks

Tags: stripe-payments

I manage several webhooks in my Stripe account, for example

Webhook 1 for Site 1
Webhook 2 for Site 2

When I perform a Stripe Checkout with a successful payment, the 2 webhooks are called. I find this inappropriate since inevitably there is 1 of the 2 which returns a 400 error.

How to choose the webhook that you want to run?

Comment: You can't. If an event happens on a Stripe account it goes to all the webhooks on that account that listen to that event type. I would use separate Stripe accounts for your different businesses(https://stripe.com/docs/multiple-accounts); or use Stripe Connect if that suits your use cases; or define a single endpoint that can look at the event, return a 200 to Stripe, and then just send the data to the right internal part of your system for the given site.

Comment: It's a pity! thanks

Comment: In my opinion that's a flaw in the Stripe API, not a feature.
Each webhook has a unique ID, though it is not even transmitted.
I believe they wanted to do this properly (specify webhook ID during payment) but forgot about it during development.
The only way I know is to never change the "statement descriptor" and then reject the wrong statement descriptors on each size ("calculated_statement_descriptor" is sent in webhook).
That's a ugly solution but it works, of course it does not prevent to leak all events to all sites.